# Why does the expression 'a'>'b' return false in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

print('a'>'b')
Returns False
similar to this 
print('a'>'A')
Returns True

Comment: Python is comparing the Unicode value of each char.  'a' = 61, 'b' = 62, and 'A' = 41.

Answer (score 4):

Python uses Lexicographical ordering for strings. This means that it uses the `Unicode` point number to order characters.

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

You may find this useful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3 uses unicode**

Each character has a value according to the ASCII table:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

'a' = 97

'b' = 98

'A' = 65

Which is why **97 > 98** returns false

Comment: This is incorrect. Python uses Lexicographical ordering (Unicode), not ASCII. Check my answer.

Comment: probably python 2 uses ascii?

Comment: OP has the `python-3.x` tag on his post.